# Using string replace() to get a value from a DB query result leads to problems

Tags: python, database, robotframework

I am querying DB and want to validation my output. The result from DB is coming in the manner -> `(('ABC',),)` and I want to validate it with string 'ABC', but I am unable due to extra characters received in my db output .

Can anybody help me with how to remove extra characters that are coming as output from DB?

I tried using Evaluate function:

```
Evaluate   '(('ABC',),)'.replace('(',' ')
```

I need result as just ABC.

Answer (score 3):

Do not do that - treat the response as a string, and try to get you data out through string replace.

The response is an object - a list of tuples, it actually looks like this:

```
[('ABC',),]
```

Every tuple in the list is a response row; every member of the tuple is a column in that row.

To get the first column of the first row, you just address them (their indices start from 0):

```
${value}=    Set Variable    ${the response object}[0][0]
```

---

If for example the query returnes 3 rows, each with 2 columns:

```
[('ABC', 'DEF'), ('GHI', 'JKL'), ('MNO', 'PQR')]
```

, you'd get the 3rd row's (index: 2) 2nd column (index: 1) - the string 'PQR' - with this:

```
${value}=    Set Variable    ${the response object}[2][1]
```

Now I hope you understand why using string replace (over the string representation of a two-dimensional list) is not a good idea.