# How to concatenate the DB query result in Robot framework

Tags: python, database, robotframework

I am doing Select query on a Database which return a result as

```
((596,),)
```

i want to use only 596 and set that as global variable and use it to next test case.

How to concatenate and get only 596 value and use in other tests?

Query -

```
${id}=  Execute Select Query  SELECT id FROM <table> where name="Path" and uid="123"
```

```
Actual Result - ((596,),)
Expected Result - 596
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using string replace() to get a value from a DB query result leads to problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296712/using-string-replace-to-get-a-value-from-a-db-query-result-leads-to-problems)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting back a list of lists. You should be able to use robot's [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) to get the first column of the first row like so: `${id[0][0]}`

Accessing individual list items is also covered in the user guide under the section titled [Accessling list and dictionary items](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#accessing-list-and-dictionary-items), which shows putting the list item index outside of the curly braces: `${id}[0][0]`.